# Panel slide up effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a panel who scroll to top with a fixed content under.

I would like to have this effect : [Curtain JS](http://www.the.gs/fresh/curtain/example/)

I don't want to use Curtain JS plugin because I only need the first effect. That the first panel be scrolled and when he disappeared be deleted. In fact that's it's effect be played once.

So I try this : [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/8oc0dur1/)

But the content under isn't fixed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $vertical = $('#vertical');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(this).height();

        scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

        var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).height() - $vertical.height()));

        $vertical.css({
            'bottom': position
        });
    });
});
```

Can I have some help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/1wtaofr2/1/
Js:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $vertical = $('#vertical');

    $('body').height($('.test').height() + $vertical.height());

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(this).height();

        scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

        var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).height() - $vertical.height()));

        $vertical.css({
            "-webkit-transform":"translateY(-"+ position +"px)"
        });

        if (position > $vertical.height()) {
            $('.test').css({
            position: 'relative',
            'padding-top': $vertical.height()
          })
        }

        if (position < $vertical.height()) {
            $('.test').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            'padding-top': 0
          })
        }
    });
});
```

Css:

```
body {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#vertical {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

In case you want to use an external library, maybe you will find [scrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) useful.